# How can I access class variables in an ExtJS event handler?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

```
this.getUrl = 'test';
this.items.add(
      new Ext.form.Checkbox(
            {
              listeners: {
                check: function(checkbox, checked) {
                  alert(this.getUrl);
                },
             }
       )
)
```

How do I access `this.getUrl` in the check handler?

Comment: @Abdel: Why did you remove the extjs4 tag from this question? If he's on version 4 he should use `Ext.Function.bind`, but if he's on 3 or less he should use `Function.createDelegate` to change the function scope.  In this case, the version is significant.

Comment: @wes, correct me if I am wrong.. there is NO `check` event for checkbox in extjs4.

Comment: Very perceptive! I missed that. Furthermore, if he was on v4, it would be Ext.form.field.Checkbox. I'll update my answer :)

Comment: @wes, I have brought back the extjs4 tag.. but I wonder how the event worked for him... I will give it a try 2moro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to access the property `getUrl`. Here are the few possible options:

**1. Use Ext.getCmp**: If you set an `id` for your FormPanel (or other extjs component whatever you are using), you can access it using `Ext.getCmp()` method. So,

```
 var yourComponent = Ext.getCmp('yourComponentId');
 alert(yourComponent.getUrl);
```

**2. Use OwnerCt property**: If you need to access your parent container (If the parent is holding your checkbox) you can access the parent container through the public property `OwnerCt`.

**3. Use refOwner property**: If you use `ref` system in your code, you can make use of this property to get hold of the container and access the required variable.

I think it will be easy for you to go with the first option.

Answer (score 12):

I wonder why nobody has suggested the obvious, just do it the Ext way and use the 'scope' config property:

```
this.getUrl = 'test';
this.items.add(
    new Ext.form.Checkbox(
            {
            listeners: {
                check: function(checkbox, checked) {
                    alert(this.getUrl);
                },
                scope: this
            }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Event handlers are usually called from a different scope (`this` value). If all you want is a single value in the handler, lexical scoping is the easiest way to go:

```
var getUrl = 'test';  // now it's just a regular variable
this.items.add(
      new Ext.form.Checkbox(
            {
              listeners: {
                check: function(checkbox, checked) {
                  alert(getUrl); // still available - lexical scope!
                },
             }
       )
)
```

Or if you really do want the parent object available as `this` in your event handler, you can use `Ext.Function.bind` to modify the scope:

```
this.getUrl='test';
this.items.add(
      new Ext.form.Checkbox(
            {
              listeners: {
                check: Ext.Function.bind( function(checkbox, checked) {
                  alert(this.getUrl);
                }, this ),  // second arg tells bind what to use for 'this'
             }
       )
)
```

Update: `Ext.Function.bind` is an ExtJS 4 feature.  If you're on ExtJS 3.x or lower, you can use `Function.createDelegate` to the same end:

```
this.getUrl='test';
this.items.add(
      new Ext.form.Checkbox(
            {
              listeners: {
                check: function(checkbox, checked) {
                  alert(this.getUrl);
                }.createDelegate(this)
             }
       )
)
```