# JavaScript object construction

Tags: javascript, extjs

Usually an ExtJS component/object is constructed by passing a config object to it's constructor, e.g.

```
    this.serviceFiltersPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
        title: 'some title',
        layout:'anchor',
        buttonAlign: 'left',
        buttons: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Click Me',
                handler: function () {

                    // How do I get a reference to the FormPanel 
                    // under construction here?
                });
            }
        ]
    });
```

Is there any way to get a reference to the `FormPanel` object being constructed from inside the button handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var formPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    title: 'some title',
    layout:'anchor',
    buttonAlign: 'left',
    buttons: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Click Me',
            handler: function () {

                // Q: How do I get a reference to the FormPanel 
                // under construction here?

                // A: use the formPanel variable.
            });
        }
    ]
});

this.serviceFiltersPanel = formPanel;
```

Comment: I was assuming that `formPanel` is only assigned once the constructor has finished execution. Can you explain why is it necessary to assign the `FormPanel` to two variables? In other words, why can't I just assign it to `serviceFiltersPanel` as in the question, then refer to that variable inside the handler?

Comment: @Don, it's only available there because it's a global variable. And you are correct, but handler is called after construction anyway and the variable exists in global, so it can read it.

Comment: @Don, the constructor finishes executing way before the button handler runs. You just pass in the (un-executed) button handler to the constructor. As to why I'm saving it in a separate variable, that's because inside the handler `this` will refer to something different, so using `this.serviceFiltersPanel` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do it is to use binding inside constructor but in extJS
there seems to be many ways to do this as I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967348/how-can-i-access-class-variables-in-an-extjs-event-handler).

As a quick regular js hack you could do this but it's not very DRY:

```
this.serviceFiltersPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    title: 'some title',
    layout:'anchor',
    buttonAlign: 'left',
    buttons: [
        {

        xtype: 'button',

        text: 'Click Me',

        handler: (function( obj ) {

                return function(){
                //obj.serviceFiltersPanel refers to the FormPanel instance created. This is the real function body,
                //the outer function is immediately executed.
                };

            })(this)
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are likely dozen ways to accomplish this - here is another (Ext JS 3.x).

```
MyFormClass = Ext.extend( Ext.form.FormPanel, 
{
   /**
    * constructor (private) - 
    */
   constructor: function( params )  
   {
       var somePrivateVariable = true;      


    // A private event handler
    var _handleClickEvent = function( cmp ) {

        // I can reference somePrivateVariable
        // cmp is provided as a parameter

    }.createDelegate(this);   // force scope to instance of MyFormClass


    // Remainder of constructor
    argsForParent = {};
    argsForParent.collapsed = false;
    argsForParent.width = 320;
    argsForParent.items = [{
        xtype: 'button',
        click: _handleClickEvent
    }];
    argsForParent.listeners = [ ... ];

    // Declare my custom events
    this.addEvents( 'myCustomEvent' );

        MyFormClass.superclass.constructor.apply( this, [ argsForParent ]);
    } });   

Ext.reg( 'someXtype', MyFormClass );
```